# pg_query error going directly to console, while pg_last_error returns nothing

Tags: php, postgresql, error-handling, pg-query

I'm updating some legacy PHP code and trying to get some decent error logging.  All calls to the DB now go through this function:

```
private function dbQuery($sql) {
        if (DEBUG) print("\n" . $sql . "\n");
        $result = pg_query($this->dbh, $sql);
        if ($result == FALSE) print("DB Error: " . pg_last_error($this->dbh) . "\n");
        return $result;
    }
```

But, in at least one case, the error is appearing in the console all by itself (as a PHP Warning), while pg_last_error returns nothing (even though the result of the pg_query call is FALSE).  Actual output:

```
insert into pull_count (show_pull_item_id, count_pulled, created, modified) values (1076028, 1, NOW(), NOW())
PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation pull_count in /var/www/html/src/backend/engine.php on line 1740
DB Error:
```

And in the calling function, where we again call pg_last_error(), we still get nothing.

So... what's the deal?  Why is the error going to the console, and not to pg_last_error -- and how can I fix it?

Comment: More investigation shows that it has nothing to do with the permissions error... if my query string contains any error at all, I get the same result: a PHP Warning in the console, and nothing at all from pg_last_error().  Is there a configuration setting somewhere that affects this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out I'm an idiot... the code wasn't getting pushed to the server properly, so I was testing older code that looked like this:

```
private function dbQuery($sql) {
    if (DEBUG) print("\n" . $sql . "\n");
    $result = pg_query($this->dbh, $sql);
    if ($result == FALSE) print("DB Error: " . pg_last_error() . "\n");
    return $result;
}
```

Note the failure to include the DB connection handle in the pg_last_error call.  This is why it failed to return any result.

With that corrected, I still get a PHP Warning in the console, but I *also* get a proper pg_last_error, so all is right with the world.